# Being X a continous random variablewith density $f(x)$ and distribution $F(x)$. Additionaly, for a given value $x_{0}$. Is defined the function:

Tags: probability

$$g(x)=\begin{cases}
  f(x)/[1-F(x_{0})]    & \quad \text{if } x \text{$\geq x_0$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{if } x \text{$<x_0$}
  \end{cases}$$

Suppose that $F(x_{0})<1$

Prove that g(x) is a density function.

The first condition $g(x)\geq0$ is very easy to prove. But the second $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) dx=1$ does not come up easily. How can I prove it?

Comment: When $F(x_0)\in(0,1)$ then $(1-F(x_0))\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} g(x)dx=\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x)dx=(1-F(x_0))$ . Therefore $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)=1$. ( Corrected comment ).

Comment: The first step is to spot $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)\, dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x_0} g(x)\, dx + \int\limits_{x_0}^{\infty} g(x)\, dx$

Comment: @KurtG. $g(x)$ looks like a truncated density to me and does integrate to $1$

Comment: @Henry . Yep ! Corrected within 5 min.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx=\int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac {f(x)} {1-F(x_0)}dx$$ $$=\frac 1 {1-F(x_0)} \int_{x_0}^{\infty} f(x)dx=\frac {1-F(x_0)}  {1-F(x_0)} =1$$

Answer (score 1):

The integral is
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x)dx=\frac{1}{1-F(x_0)}\int_{x_0}^\infty f(x)dx$$

I suppose $F$ ist the corresponding cumulative distribution function. Think about its properties, for example $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=1$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$. Then the last integral should be immediate to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Just plug in the definition:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x) dx= \int_{x_0}^{\infty} \frac{f(x)}{1-F(x_0)} dx = \frac{1-F(x_0)}{1-F(x_0)}=1$$
since $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)=1$.